# Numpy 2D- Array from Buffer?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an memory map, which contains a 2D array and I would like to make a numpy array from it. Ideally, i would like to avoid copying, since the involved array can be big.

My code looks like this:

```
n_bytes = 10000
tagname = "Some Tag from external System"
map = mmap.mmap(-1, n_bytes, tagname)
offsets = [0, 5000]

columns = []
for offset in offsets:
   #type and count vary in the real code, but for this dummy code I simply made them up. But I know the count and type for every column.
   np_type = np.dtype('f4')
   column_data = np.frombuffer(map, np_type, count=500, offset=offset)
   columns.append(column_data)

# this line seems to copy the data, which I would like to avoid
data = np.array(columns).T
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the whole file as a big 1D array, and then reshape it to a 2D array?

Comment: Do you know in advance the size of your final array?

Comment: @kennytm The data can habe different dtypes per column ( e.g. the first block is a float, the second an int), which I cannot express in the buffer method

Comment: @ Julien Bernu Jes, I know how many columns, rows and bytes there are-

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you have a byte array and you know it's dimensions the answer is very simple.
imagine you raw RGB data of an image (24 bit per pixel) in a buffer (named 'buff')
dimensions are 1024x768

```
#read the buffer into 1D byte array
arr = numpy.frombuffer(buff, dtype=numpy.uint8)
#now shape the array as you please
arr.shape = (768,1024,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used `frombuffer` much, but I think the `np.array` works with those arrays as it does with conventionally constructed ones.

Each `column_data` array will have its own data buffer - the mmap you assigned it.  But `np.array(columns)` reads the values from each array in the list, and constructs a new array from them, with its own data buffer.

I like to use `x.__array_interface__` to look at the data buffer location (and to see other key attributes).  Compare that dictionary for each element of `columns` and for `data`.

You can construct a 2d array from a mmap - using a contiguous block.  Just make the 1d `frombuffer` array, and `reshape` it.  Even `transpose` will continue to use that buffer (with `F` order).  Slices and views also use it.

But unless you are real careful you'll quickly get copies that put the data elsewhere.  Simply `data1 = data+1` makes a new array, or advance indexing `data[[1,3,5],:]`.  Same for any `concatenation`.

2 arrays from bytestring buffers:

```
In [534]: x=np.frombuffer(b'abcdef',np.uint8)
In [535]: y=np.frombuffer(b'ghijkl',np.uint8)
```

a new array by joining them

```
In [536]: z=np.array((x,y))

In [538]: x.__array_interface__
Out[538]: 
{'data': (3013090040, True),
 'descr': [('', '|u1')],
 'shape': (6,),
 'strides': None,
 'typestr': '|u1',
 'version': 3}
In [539]: y.__array_interface__['data']
Out[539]: (3013089608, True)
In [540]: z.__array_interface__['data']
Out[540]: (180817384, False)
```

the data buffer locations for `x,y,z` are totally different

But the data for reshaped `x` doesn't change

```
In [541]: x.reshape(2,3).__array_interface__['data']
Out[541]: (3013090040, True)
```

nor does the 2d transpose

```
In [542]: x.reshape(2,3).T.__array_interface__
Out[542]: 
{'data': (3013090040, True),
 'descr': [('', '|u1')],
 'shape': (3, 2),
 'strides': (1, 3),
 'typestr': '|u1',
 'version': 3}
```

Same data, different view

```
In [544]: x
Out[544]: array([ 97,  98,  99, 100, 101, 102], dtype=uint8)
In [545]: x.reshape(2,3).T
Out[545]: 
array([[ 97, 100],
       [ 98, 101],
       [ 99, 102]], dtype=uint8)
In [546]: x.reshape(2,3).T.view('S1')
Out[546]: 
array([[b'a', b'd'],
       [b'b', b'e'],
       [b'c', b'f']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer!
Do you know how I can use frombuffer method when the column sizes vary? e.g. my first block contains f4, but the second f8 - I would have to do some reshaping after building the 2d array?

Comment: Structured arrays allow different dtypes in fields.  But in such an array an `f4` element will next to a `f8`, etc, in `records`, not as separate columns (blocks of `f4`, separate blocks of `f8`).  I don't know of a way of mixing columns and dtypes.